# Haven't got revised employment yet

Tags: hiring-process, negotiation, resignation, hiring

I have already got employment contract via email. But it is just draft only. So, I discussed with my employer everything I wanna know about my salary and benefits etc via email only. My employer said he will send revised contract soon. It's almost one week ago and I haven't received any revised contract yet.

Is it safe to have all these discussion via email only, even if they haven't provided the revised contract yet? Shall I proceed to resign without receiving revised contract?

I am just worried that after I resign from current job, they may not revise accordingly what we discussed.

Comment: Voting to close as unclear. It appears that you are changing jobs and that you are discussing employment contracts with a prospective employer. But I don't want to be answering questions based on my best guess as to what the question is.

Comment: possible duplicate of [When is the right time to give my notice to leave my current company?](http://workplace.stackexchange.com/questions/6731/when-is-the-right-time-to-give-my-notice-to-leave-my-current-company)

Answer (score 7):

Don't resign before you have a written contract, ink on paper. Email discussions are just that, discussions. In your position, you want to (friendly) remind the hiring person to finalize the contract. Call them, ask them about where the hangup is and if they need to clarify more things with you. Remind them that you won't resign your current position without a valid, binding contract. Even if you hear something along the line "You're fine, just quit your job, we'll hash it out don't wait for the contract" remain firm. The hiring person knows it's the professional thing to do, even if they pretend otherwise.

There are possible reasons that you don't have your contract yet:

- They are interviewing someone else and have not totally committed to you, but won't tell you
- The funds or the project your new position hinges on is stalled, they are waiting for this to clear before committing
- By far, FAR the most likely reason: They simply haven't gotten around to finalizing the contract

But the first two options should be reason enough for you to wait for the proper contract.