# How do I tell my boss I've accepted an internship at another company, but I would like to continue working part time?

Tags: professionalism, job-change, part-time

I've been working at my current job part-time for a few years. Just a few days before we were asked to submit our summer hours of availability, I was offered an internship at another company, which I accepted.

What makes this different from [When is the right time to give my notice to leave my current company?](https://workplace.stackexchange.com/questions/6731/when-is-the-right-time-to-give-my-notice-to-leave-my-current-company) is that I want to continue working part-time at my current job. However, I can't submit my hours of availability until I'm given my new work schedule for my internship.

**How should I tell my boss I've accepted an internship at another company, but I would like to continue my current part-time job if my schedule permits it?**

Comment: Is the new job in the same field as the previous one?  If so, there might be some conflict of interest / NDA type issues that would leave your current boss disinclined to let you work in both places at once.  The same reasoning could also get you in trouble at the new place, so if this is the case, you  should probably reconsider working in both places at once.

Comment: @Steve-O My current job is a part-time student job at my university. It doesn't have any NDAs.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The only answer is to tell them.  You can find a nice interpersonal way, especially since you worked there 3 years already, but just honestly tell them.

- I would stress your great appreciation for the opportunity to work with them for 3 years and your continued desire to work with them part time.
- I would also relay exactly what the internship is and why their company cannot offer you that specific desired experience.

Being honest and open about your career aspirations as well as what each company offers while maintaining gratitude should lessen the blow and maintain a bridge for the company even if they don't have part time work for you.  You may want to work with them in the future should circumstances align that way.

Comment: After telling this to my boss, he congratulated me and told me he would see if any shifts were available once I had my hours. So I'd say this was the right advice.

Comment: I'm happy for you and congrats!