# How bad is my situation for job searching?

Tags: job-search, new-job, job-change

I'm wondering how bad it'd be if I quit my current job and go searching for a new one.
...

What would happen if I quit my job and go job searching? I have no side projects or github page and I'm having trouble coming up with optimal leetcode solutions (aka I suck at leetcode).

Comment: [When is the right time to give my notice to leave my current company?](https://workplace.stackexchange.com/q/6731) [Why shouldn't I resign when I haven't secured another job?](https://workplace.stackexchange.com/q/16816)

Comment: "What would happen?" is a *very* broad question. Are you asking how it would be perceived on your resume? Are you asking how risky it would be? Are you asking how your finances would change? Or what your family would think? Please narrow your question to what you are specifically asking about, and make sure that it remains [on-topic for The Workplace](https://workplace.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic).

Comment: Not everyone knows what https://leetcode.com/ is - especially when you don't give a URL

Comment: “Quit my job and start job searching” is doing things in the wrong order. Find a job, sign the contract, give notice.

Answer (score 4):

> What would happen if I quit my job and go job searching?

**Never do this** unless you absolutely have no choice, its **always** easier to find a job if your currently employed.

Think about it, if you leave, you have to explain that.  It may be easy, it may not be, but if you stay you can always explain that your looking for a new job because of:

1. Lack of upward mobility
2. Not being paid market value
3. Benefits are not good

Notice in the three reasons I listed *I did not talk bad about my boss or the company I am currently working for*.

**Short answer**:  Keep your job, find another one, don't bad mouth current company, work your notice period, and then start new gig.

Comment: To be fair, there are ways of explaining it without badmouthing your previous employer even if you have quit. You want to get involved in another market / you are moving, and it was easier to interview in person in the new area quitting first and then moving, etc etc