# How to go through resigning when I'm the only developer in the company?

Tags: professionalism, resignation

I've been with this company for 2 years now and I'm the only developer. In that 2 years I've developed 1 web application and 1 mobile app. Now I am being given new task but I'm already planning to resign once I get a job offer.

This was my first job as a fresh graduate and I'm really thankful for the opportunity they gave me so I don't want to burn any bridges.

My questions is:

1. Should I keep accepting this tasks?
2. Should I actually wait for a job offer to file my resignation?
3. Is there anything I can do to help them with the applications before I leave?

Comment: "Is there anything I can do for them to still be able use the applications?" What does this mean? Which applications?

Comment: The web application was made with php and google sheets as database. The mobile app was an android application. I want them to understand how this application works at least and continue to use it.

Comment: You mean want use (as a consumer) the application that you developed after you leave?

Comment: @GregoryCurrie Sorry, I phrased the question wrong. Those applications are mainly used for internal events and information keeping of reports.

Comment: It would be really good if you edited your question to rephrase.

Comment: "Should I actually wait for a job offer to file my resignation?"  Yes, always.  Never even hint that you might be moving to another job until you have the job offer in your hand. What would you do if you said "Hey, boss #1, I'm going to another job" and then company #2 changed their minds?

Comment: For your second question: [When is the right time to give my notice to leave my current company?](https://workplace.stackexchange.com/q/6731)

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Your situation is exactly like every other person wanting to change companies.

There is no benefit for you to tell them before you have to.

> My questions is:
>
> 1. Should I keep accepting this tasks?
> 2. Should I actually wait for a job offer to file my resignation?
> 3. Is there anything I can do to help them with the applications before I leave?

1. Yes, keep accepting tasks. It could be months before you are ready to start the new job. So trying to duck tasks won't work forever.
2. Don't resign until you have returned to the new employer the signed offer letter with no contingencies. Don't resign any earlier than that. Pick your resignation date based on your required notice period, and the negotiated start date.
3. Try to leave as much documentation and clean code as you can. It is rare that the leaving employee trains their replacement unless they replace from within or the company has a very quick hiring cycle. You may end up doing a data dump with a non-programmer.

Leaving this way reduces the likelihood of burned bridges. There is no way to 100% avoid burning bridges, some companies or managers are insulted by anybody leaving. In those cases letting them know months in advance just makes those last weeks super stressful.

Comment: Thanks for this. I decided to let them know once i’ve already signed an offer. I’ll probably just wait for them to ask me for help regarding the applications.

Answer (score 1):

Before you leave, try to convert the Google sheets backend to an actual database.

This will makes things smoother.

Comment: I’ve already discussed this with them. They preferred using google sheets as the UI of it is easily understood by non programmers which I can understand. I’m planning on creating a google acc for them to pass the API credentials that’s currently on my google acc.

Comment: I disagree with the advice.  A proper DB is a major refactoring which will introduce lots of other changes; now is not the time for that.  The OP should concentrate on improving the documentation (and doing things like linking with a proper company account and not his private account).

Answer (score 0):

The best way not to burn a bridge is the way you do it. Just don't up and put in your 2 weeks. Go in and have a discussion with your manager. Talk about your goals and why you are interested in moving on. In a friendly way discuss your perspective. You will be surprised that maybe your current employer will even want to keep you there and promote you for it. Or even help you on your next path.

The best thing you can do is say that you're willing to help them with the transition while they find someone else as well.

If you do these things the relationship will be healthy as you move on. You never know when you might need each other again!