# Notifying employer of job offer

Tags: job-offer, resignation

I have accepted a conditional job offer (subject to background checks) and am yet to tell my current employers.

The plan is to wait until the offer is firm before handing my resignation and breaking in my news.

However, not breaking the news is making me feel very uncomfortable at work.

Is it best to wait or just do it anyway?

Comment: out of interest: what is a conditional job offer ?

Comment: subject to background checks

Comment: Ah ok. Understood.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [When is the right time to give my notice to leave my current company?](https://workplace.stackexchange.com/questions/6731/when-is-the-right-time-to-give-my-notice-to-leave-my-current-company)

Answer (score 15):

*Join your hands, close your eyes and repeat after me: Never hand out the notice and break the news until you have another confirmed offer sealed and settled in stone.*

> *The plan is to wait until the offer is firm before handing my resignation and breaking in my news*

Given that by saying "offer is firm" you mean the contract is signed, it's a good plan, follow it without second thoughts. In case the contract is yet to be signed, go back to the beginning of the answer and re-read the first sentence.

Answer (score 4):

I agree with the above answer, but wanted to highlight that you should check your contact/company to see exactly how long your notice time is, to ensure you don't  try and hand your notice in a week before starting your new job, when your contract states you must give two weeks notice!

Comment: Well, this really **should not** affect the decision of when to hand out the notice and inform - it's **after** the contract is finalized. Whatever notice period has to be served, that needs to be taken into account while negotiating the date of joining to the new job.

Comment: @SouravGhosh That is true, but not all jobs allow you to negotiate the joining date.

Comment: Has been hinted at, the next company will take your notice period when they decide when your start date will be.  After all, if they want you to honor your notice period with them, they should allow you to honor your current notice period.

Comment: Already agreed for the Start date to be flexible.